# Can i use an independent variable in % units in a probit regression

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, predictor, genstat

I want to do a probit regression and one explanatory variable is given in % units. Do i have to transform it in decimal units or can i use it in % units in my probit regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use explanatory variables that are percentages in "probit" regression.

It is probably worth clarifying that there are two types of model that are sometimes referred to as "probit regression".

1. The first is a somewhat dated model which can still be performed in `genstat`. I am not entirely sure about the formulation of them, but they seem to allow for the use of either a clog-log, logit or probit link. I am not sure who still uses these or why though.
2. Generalised linear models (GLMs) with binomial errors and a *probit link*. These binomial models can use the three links mentioned above, although probit is not commonly used anymore, as logit is more interpretable and clog-log tends to deal with greater than binomial dispersion better.